# REST API - Get an order by order id

Tags: rest-api

what would be the end point for get an order details by order id? I have access to all API requests. Also which key should I use? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint for getting an order's details by order ID will depend on the specific API you are working with.

For example

```
 https://api.example.com/orders/{order_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get an order by its ID using Magento 2 REST API. Here are the steps:

1. Get the Access Token

To use the REST API, you need to get the access token. You can get the access token by following the Magento 2 documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

2. Send the GET request

Once you have the access token, you can send the GET request to the following endpoint:

```
<Magento 2 Base URL>/rest/V1/orders/{id}
```

Replace {id} with the ID of the order you want to retrieve.

For example, if the ID of the order you want to retrieve is 100, then the endpoint will be:

```
<Magento 2 Base URL>/rest/V1/orders/100
```

3. Parse the response

The response of the GET request will be in JSON format. You can parse the response to get the details of the order.

Here is an example response:

```
{
  "entity_id": 100,
  "status": "complete",
  "state": "complete",
  "total_qty_ordered": 1,
  "subtotal": 100,
  "base_subtotal": 100,
  "grand_total": 110,
  "base_grand_total": 110,
  "customer_email": "john@example.com",
  "customer_firstname": "John",
  "customer_lastname": "Doe",
  "customer_group_id": 1,
  "billing_address": {...},
  "shipping_address": {...},
  "items": [...],
  "payment": {...},
  "created_at": "2022-04-08 08:30:00",
  "updated_at": "2022-04-08 08:35:00"
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Hello! thank you for your quick reply. =) 

however, I just tried this end point "https://www.justjeeps.com//rest/V1/orders/200038492"

and I am getting this error:

{
    "message": "The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again."
}

I am using access token and have access to all api from integration.

Comment: Verify that the order ID you are passing in the API request is correct and matches the ID of an existing order in your Magento. Ensure that you are using the correct API endpoint for retrieving order information in Magento. The correct endpoint for retrieving an order by ID is rest/V1/orders/{id} where {id} is the ID of the order you want to retrieve.   Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I can get the most recent order with the end point below, however, I cannot get the information from an order_id!

```
https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

may be you are using increment id in the endpoint, try to use entity id for the order if you want to use this endpoints.

> [https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders/{{entity_id_here}}](https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders/%7B%7Bentity_id_here%7D%7D)

I guess 200038492 is your increment id, you can use this endpoints,

> [https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=**INCREMENT_ID_HERE**&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=eq](https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B2%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=increment_id&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B2%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=**INCREMENT_ID_HERE**&searchCriteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B2%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=eq)